# Printing list of strings

Tags: python, list, printing

I am completely new to python, and am trying to print some elements of my list. In second print() I am getting error, which is: 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'.
The output should be The sum of digits operation performs 1+4. Where am I wrong?

```
def sum_of_digits(s):
  letters = []
  numbers = []

  for i in s:
    if i.isalpha():
     letters.append(i)
    elif i.isdigit():
      numbers.append(i)
  print("The extracted non-digits are: {} ". format(letters), end="\n")    
  print("The sum of digits operation performs ", s.join(int(i, numbers[i])))

sum_of_digits("1aw4")
```

Comment: `s.join(numbers)`. You don't need `i`.

Comment: with this I am getting: The sum of digits operation performs  11aw44

Comment: Why are you using `s` as the delimiter when you're joining? Use `"".join(numbers)` to join them with no delimiter between them.

Comment: You may provide the expected output please [edit] and add it

Comment: @Barmar now what it looks like: 1The sum of digits operation performs 4

Comment: I tested the code in my answer and it works correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing differently.

Comment: If you have comments about my answer, enter them below the answer. These comments are about the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`numbers[i]` causes that error because `i` is a string (it's the last character from the `for i in s:` loop). Since `numbers` is a list, indexes must be integers, not strings.

The argument to `join` should just be the list of strings that you want to join. You don't need to call `int()`, and you don't need to use `i`.

The `join()` method should be called on the string that you want to be the delimiter between each of the elements when they're joined. If you just want to concatenate all the elements, use an empty string, not `s`.

```
print("The sum of digits operation performs ", "".join(numbers))
```

This prints:

```
The sum of digits operation performs  14
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/fUeu1g)

Comment: not working for me... Can I have a look at your code?

Comment: I am getting this: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: There's nothing in your code that convert the strings to integers, so that shouldn't happen.

Comment: That would happen if you did `numbers.append(int(i))` in the loop.

Comment: I've added a link to a demo showing that my code works without error.

Comment: My code is a copy of your code with this one line changed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine `s.join(int(i, numbers[i]))`

- `int(a,b)` mean convert `a` as an `int` with base `b`, for example

  ```
  int('11011', 2)  # 27
  int('11011', 8)  # 4617
  int('11011', 10) # 11011
  ```

  and `i` in your case is the last char of the string, even `numbers[i]` is not possible (that's where the exception is)
- `s.join` would mean to put the original `s` string between each value of the given parameter, non-sens too

---

You may convert to int each char that is a digit, then just use `sum`

#### Sum result

```
def sum_of_digits(s):
    letters = []
    numbers = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isalpha():
            letters.append(i)
        elif i.isdigit():
            numbers.append(int(i))
    print("The extracted non-digits are: {} ".format(letters), end="\n")
    print("The sum of digits operation performs ", sum(numbers))

The extracted non-digits are: ['a', 'w']
The sum of digits operation performs  5
```

---

#### Sum operation

```
def sum_of_digits(s):
    letters = []
    numbers = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isalpha():
            letters.append(i)
        elif i.isdigit():
            numbers.append(i)
    print("The extracted non-digits are: {} ".format(letters), end="\n")
    print("The sum of digits operation performs ", "+".join(numbers))


The extracted non-digits are: ['a', 'w']
The sum of digits operation performs  1+4
```

Comment: Thanks but i want output to be e.g for argument ("1aw3), "The sum of digits operation performs 1+ 3

Comment: @user17402153 see my edit and tell me about the last thing